# Failed in getBuildApi with error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 13.107.42.18:443

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

In my project, I have configured more than 1 deployment group job in the pipeline.
When I trigger the deployment I am facing the timeout error on the download artifact task [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrrrt.png)

`Failed in getBuildApi with error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 13.107.42.18:443`

This timeout error is occurring randomly in one of the deployment group job while (downloading the artifacts) meanwhile the same task get succeed for other deployment group job in the same pipeline.

I am not sure what the problem here with my project. Can anyone please help me with to resolve this issue.

Comment: I think your Internet has some problems. Please check if you have used some proxies or if the firewall prevent the internet. You should check it carefully. Or you could change another Internet or restore the Internet environment to test it.

Comment: The internet speed in the server is 1Gbps, which I think so is pretty good. I checked for the proxies and firewall and that's also seems fine to me.